# Gaussian Processes Probabilistic Least Squares Classifier - Leave one Out Cross-Validation Means, Variances Shape?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, gaussian-process

I am currently working on implementing some of the algorithms covered in Rasmussen and Williams' book, and stuck on a particular part in chapter 5 ([link to the chapter here](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW5.pdf)).

In particular, on page 117, in equation 5.12, there seem to be major explanations missing there, the most important of which being that one would expect both the LOO-CV mean and variance at a single training point to be a single value - the point I'm stuck on/need help clarifying.

EDIT: I should clarify that below, the subscript $_{i}$ indicates that it is the $i^{th}$ row that is removed before inversion, and subscript $_{ii}$ that the $i^{th}$ row *and* column are removed before inversion. The syntax is misleading, but can be found appropriately in some papers, as well as directly implied by the preceding and subsequent paragraph where these equations are (by way of explanations of efficiency of inverting the covariance matrix over and over).

However,

$$\mu_i = y_i - \frac{[K^{-1}y]_i}{[K^{-1}]_{ii}}$$

is, to my understanding, an $m \times m$ matrix, where $m = n-1$, and $n$ is the size of the square covariance matrix. The same goes for the other equation,

$$\sigma_i^2 = \frac{1}{[K^{-1}]_{ii}} $$

which also produces an $m \times m$ matrix as opposed to a single value.

I'm sure that I have misunderstood something (possibly quite fundamental/basic), or am missing some implied knowledge of some sort that would solve my supposed problem.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the previous page, they state that the subscript $-i$ refers to the $i$th row being removed before inversion. I believe that in their notation $a_{i}$ refers to the $i$th element of vector $a$, and likewise, $A_{ii}$ refers to the $i$th element on the diagonal of matrix $A$.

So for the mean:

$y_i$ is a scalar. $[K^{-1}\mathbf{y}]$ is a vector, and thus $[K^{-1}\mathbf{y}]_i$ is the $i$th element of that vector. $K^{-1}_{ii}$ is a scalar.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I upvoted the response but haven't hit 15 rep yet sp it doesn't show D:. I guessed as much/originally implemented it that way, and was misled by a particular paper. Is it implied the *y* in those omit the item at *i*, with the same applying to the original training data before calculating _K inverse_?